# how to enable ringtone for a specific incomming call when iphone is on silent?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, phone-call

I want to make an app which enables the ringtone while the IPhone is on silent for a specific caller which is in the list of the app. I add numbers to list and if the incoming call is from this list then the silent does not work and IPhone rings the bell.

Comment: Not possible for a non-jailbroken iPhone. Don't think apple will ever allow that.

Comment: why its not possible for non-jailbrocken Iphone? Is Apple don't let this do? Or there is no functionality in IOS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not be possible. You can not change the privacy settings of user.

Comment: Is there is any permission to do this?